# The links are not working in html file

Tags: html, css, email

I cannot figure out why the links in `<a href..>` are not working. All of them are independently functioning links. But none of them are working in this code.

I've received it from my client and need to test it. Shown is the CSS code and part of the HTML with one of the links. It doesn't look like the problem is in the HTML, so I think it must be in the CSS part. I'm not sure where though.

```css
  #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
            }
            .body{
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
            .ExternalClass {
            width:100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass,
            .ExternalClass p,
            .ExternalClass span,
            .ExternalClass font,
            .ExternalClass td,
            .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
            }
            img {
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            }
            a img {
            border: none;
            }
            p {
            margin: 1em 0;
            }
            table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            /* hide unsubscribe from forwards*/
            blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {
            display: none !important;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
            body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
            body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */
            #bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}
            #templateContainer{
            max-width:500px !important;
            width:100% !important;
            }
            h1{
            font-size:24px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            h2{
            font-size:20px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            h3{
            font-size:18px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            h4{
            font-size:16px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            #templatePreheader{display:none !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */
            #headerImage{
            height:auto !important;
            max-width:500px !important;
            width:100% !important;
            }
            .headerContent{
            font-size:20px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            .bodyContent{
            font-size:18px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            .footerContent{
            font-size:14px !important;
            line-height:100% !important;
            }
            .footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */
            }
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" id="bodyTable" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 99px; top: 74px; width: 500px; height: 800px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" id="bodyCell" valign="top" style="margin: 0px; padding: 20px; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-top-width: 4px; border-top-style: solid; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                    <table id="templateContainer" style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); border-image: none; left: 159.5px; top: 53px; width: 500px; height: 800px; border-collapse: collapse !important;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: right;">
                                <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(63, 63, 63);">&nbsp;​<img src="http://prod-content01.smashfly.com/Images/11143/11143_7445_ADG_EmailHeader_dist.png" alt="" style="">&nbsp;</span></p>
                                <p style="font-family: Helvetica; text-align: right; font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(63, 63, 63);">
                                    <a href="http://career.intel.com/i5Thc"><img src="https://recruit.smashfly.com/SmashFlyMedia/Images/11143/df4865ee-45d5-4bc1-a7a0-0ab7ff7000a1.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                                  </span>
                                </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "not working" What is the expected action, what is actually happening? What have you tried?

Comment: if you see the snippet i added from your code , you'll see that the href is working

Answer (score 0):

Remove ContentEditable="true" from your body tag and it should work. you can only click the link with contentEditable=false though there are some workarounds.